# Html5 line chart with a different color when out of area range

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, kendo-ui

I’d like to draw an arearange chart and a line on one graph and I want the line to have a black color when inside the arearange but red color when outside the arearange like on the picture.

[image]

I used the below code to draw arearange but I don't know how to make it draw the line in different color when outside of the arearange.
http://jsfiddle.net/2cVGX/

```
        $(function () {

        var limits = [
                [64064, 14.3, 27.7],
                [64928, 14.5, 27.8],
                [65792, 15.5, 29.6],
                [66656, 16.7, 30.7],
                [67520, 16.5, 25.0],
                [68384, 17.8, 25.7],
                [69248, 13.5, 24.8],
                [70112, 10.5, 21.4],
                [70976, 09.2, 23.8],
                [71840, 11.6, 21.8],
                [72704, 10.7, 23.7],
                [73568, 11.0, 23.3],
                [74432, 11.6, 23.7],
                [75296, 11.8, 20.7],
                [76160, 12.6, 22.4],
                [77024, 13.6, 19.6],
                [77888, 11.4, 22.6],
                [78752, 13.2, 25.0],
                [79616, 14.2, 21.6],
                [80480, 13.1, 17.1],
                [81344, 12.2, 15.5],
                [82208, 12.0, 20.8],
                [83072, 12.0, 17.1],
                [83936, 12.7, 18.3],
                [84800, 12.4, 19.4],
                [85664, 12.6, 19.9],
                [86528, 11.9, 20.2],
                [87392, 11.0, 19.3],
                [88256, 10.8, 17.8],
                [89120, 11.8, 18.5],
                [89984, 10.8, 16.1]
        ],
            values = [
                [64064, 21.5],
                [64928, 22.1],
                [65792, 23.0],
                [66656, 23.8],
                [67520, 21.4],
                [68384, 21.3],
                [69248, 18.3],
                [70112, 15.4],
                [70976, 16.4],
                [71840, 17.7],
                [72704, 17.5],
                [73568, 17.6],
                [74432, 17.7],
                [75296, 16.8],
                [76160, 17.7],
                [77024, 16.3],
                [77888, 17.8],
                [78752, 18.1],
                [79616, 17.2],
                [80480, 14.4],
                [81344, 13.7],
                [82208, 17.7],
                [83072, 20.6],
                [83936, 20.3],
                [84800, 19.3],
                [85664, 15.8],
                [86528, 15.2],
                [87392, 14.8],
                [88256, 14.4],
                [89120, 15],
                [89984, 13.6]
            ],

            targets = [
                [64064, 22.5],
                [64928, 23.1],
                [65792, 21.0],
                [66656, 22.8],
                [67520, 20.4],
                [68384, 22.3],
                [69248, 18.4],
                [70112, 15.5],
                [70976, 16.4],
                [71840, 17.6],
                [72704, 18.6],
                [73568, 19.6],
                [74432, 18.7],
                [75296, 17.8],
                [76160, 17.7],
                [77024, 16.5],
                [77888, 16.8],
                [78752, 17.1],
                [79616, 17.5],
                [80480, 15.4],
                [81344, 14.7],
                [82208, 16.7],
                [83072, 15.6],
                [83936, 15.3],
                [84800, 15.5],
                [85664, 15.8],
                [86528, 15.2],
                [87392, 15.8],
                [88256, 15.4],
                [89120, 15.3],
                [89984, 14.6]
            ];

        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                type: 'linear',
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                lineWidth: 0,
                tickWidth: 0
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0
            },

            tooltip: {
                crosshairs: true,
                shared: true,
                valueSuffix: 'Virt'
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                id: 'valueLine',
                name: 'Value',
                type: 'spline',
                data: values,
                zIndex: 1,
                color: 'black',
                shadow: true,

                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'black',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    radius: 2,
                    lineColor: "white",
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            }, {
                id: 'targetLine',
                name: 'Target',
                type: 'spline',
                data: targets,
                linkedTo: 'valueLine',
                zIndex: 1,
                color: 'gray',
                dashStyle: 'DashDot',
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'gray',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    radius: 2,
                    lineColor: "white",
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            }, {
                id: 'limitsArea',
                name: 'Limits',
                data: limits,
                type: 'areasplinerange',
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: 'gray',
                linkedTo: 'valueLine',
                color: "lightGray",
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                zIndex: 0
            }]

        });

    });
```

Comment: In short: it's not supported. Of course you can implement this on your own - find points where series are crossing, then create for that points separate series with specific color.

Comment: @mKlus My final attempt gets you close to what you needed :)

Comment: @PawełFus The problem with this workaround is that you can't do it with splines and areasplinerange since the new spline with the red color won't have same shape. 
Here it is implemented with lines and arearange.
http://jsfiddle.net/7NFY5/

Comment: How about using two series (red under black) and just remove points when black is outside the arearange? That should resolve problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not supported. The issue is that the line is drawn as a single path and can only have one color per path (except a gradient).

A few attempts resulted in changing color of individual points [Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/2cVGX/1/) and another based upon a threshold apply a gradient to the stroke of the path

```
function applyGraphGradient() {

    // Options
    var threshold = 19,
        colorAbove = '#F00',
        colorBelow = '#000';

    // internal
    var series = this.series[0], 
        i,
        point;

    if (this.renderer.box.tagName === 'svg') {

        var translatedThreshold = series.yAxis.translate(threshold),
            y1 = Math.round(series.yAxis.len - translatedThreshold),
            y2 = y1 + 2; // 0.01 would be fine, but IE9 requires 2

        // Apply gradient to the path
        series.graph.attr({
            stroke: {
                linearGradient: [0, y1, 0, y2],
                stops: [
                    [0, colorAbove],
                    [1, colorBelow]
                ]
            }
         });
    }


    // Apply colors to the markers
    for (i = 0; i < series.data.length; i++) {
        point = series.data[i];
        point.color = point.y < threshold ? colorBelow : colorAbove;
        if (point.graphic) {
            point.graphic.attr({
                fill: point.color
            });
        }
    }

    // prevent the old color from coming back after hover
    delete series.pointAttr.hover.fill;
    delete series.pointAttr[''].fill;

}
```

[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/2cVGX/2/), kudos to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180773/highcharts-js-setting-a-threshold-value-for-changing-column-color)

One other possible solution is to programmatically split your data into 2 series one that is in range and one that is not. by colouring the not as red it may appear to be one line

```
            var inRange = Array();
            var outRange = Array();

            for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                var range = limits[i];
                var value = values[i];

                if(value[1] > range[1] && value[1] < range[2]) {
                     inRange.push(value);
                     outRange.push([value[0],null]);
                }
                else {
                    outRange.push(value);
                    inRange.push([value[0],null]);
                }
            }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2cVGX/3/), although as you can see they don't join together

**UPDATE**

Managed to make it appear correctly

```
            var inRange = Array();
            var outRange = Array();

            var prev = 0; //1 = was valid, 2 = werent
            for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                var range = limits[i];
                var value = values[i];

                if(value[1] > range[1] && value[1] < range[2]) {
                     inRange.push(value);


                    if(prev == 2) {
                        outRange.push(value);
                    }
                    else {
                        outRange.push([value[0],null]);
                    }
                    prev = 1;
                }
                else {
                    outRange.push(value);
                    inRange.push([value[0],null]);

                    if(prev == 1) {
                       outRange[i-1][5] = values[i-1][6];
                    }

                    prev = 2;
                }

                console.log(prev);
            }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2cVGX/4/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did manage to come up with the "partial" solutions as you shown here. However, I need the "values" line to only be red if out of the area range not like in this  http://jsfiddle.net/2cVGX/4/.

Comment: I see only 2 options how I can do that:
1. Using gradient color (as you mentioned in your post). However I'm not sure how to calculate the intersection points if using spline/areasplinerange (would be easier to do if using line/arearange).
2. Draw 2 series, but again, not sure how to do that if using spline/areasplinerange since the 2 joined series will look differently to 1 series spline.

Comment: Fiddle1, Fiddle2 and example were the 3 options (the first just being coloring the markers) and yes its not perfect but it was as close as I could get to it. Although theoretically if you calculated at what point the line passes out of the area and put a marker in each series there you would have exactly what you needed. Though how to calculate that Is beyond me :)